# Can CiviCRM set up an event registration on a separate server?

Tags: civievent, webform-civicrm

Once upon a time, I seem to recall that it was possible to use pretty much any CiviCRM form and export the HTML to an external server. The idea is/was that you could have CiviCRM running on a non-advertised server and the signup or event forms on your regular Website. Is this still possible? If so, how? If not, are the only options an iframe or some other workaround?

One of my customers would like to have a server that doesn't offer the entire contact database (for security reasons) but allows for event sales or mailing list registrations which are then processed by the private CiviCRM server. There's a Webform module for CiviCRM but I believe it needs CiviCRM to be on the same machine.

Thoughts? Ideas? Suggestions?

Comment: Allowing webform to access a CiviCRM install on a separate domain would be neat. Probably a lot of work, though.

Answer (score 6):

CiviCRM profiles still have HTML snippets, which you can post on another website. They can be used for Mailing subscription forms, but if I'm right not for event subscription.

Other options I am thinking about would be:

- 2 sites, 1 CiviCRM
  http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Multi+Site+Installation
  So you are using CiviCRM with 2nd site, and only form submission via site 1
- Creating your own form on the front end site and connect with CiviCRM via the CiviCRM API

Answer (score 2):

You might [have a look at CiviProxy](https://github.com/systopia/CiviProxy). It is a proxy server that filters requests and passes "good ones" on to CiviCRM which can then be run in a VPN. Caveat: It does not have whitelisting rules for CiviEvents implemented as of now and thus would require some further development effort. But the concept and framework could be interesting for security-minded users.